# Beautiful soup: Need to click on next button to update content in a table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the data from this url: [My wescrape url](https://www.fi.se/sv/vara-register/blankningsregistret/emittent/?id=529900JY9ZBGUXGRKQ86) but I cannot figure out how to "click" on next button when web scraping using Beautiful soup. I have checked browser's dev tools in network but nothing happens when clicking on next button.  [image]

Answer (score -1):

i think they're using API for calling that table, you can use selenium to interact with that button or reverse their API

Comment: This should be a comment instead